# Округление числа путем математических операций

Tags: c++

Вот есть всем давно известный способ округления числа математическим путем, т.е без использования каких-либо функция и процедур. Выглядел этот способ как-то так:

```
digit = 3.141527;
digit = (digit*100)/100; // округление до сотых
```

Но это не работает, забыл я...Если кто-то знает этот способ, то просьба подсказать.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Наверное, вы имеете в виду

```
digit = 3.141592653589793;
digit = ((int)(digit*100 + 0.5))/100.0; // округление до сотых
```

Заметьте, что десятичные дроби не вполне точно представимы значениями типа `double`, так что вы получите результат, немного отличающийся от математически верного.

---

Обновление:
для отрицательных чисел каст в `int` работает не так, как предполагалось. Исправленный с учётом этого вариант:

```
digit = ((int)(digit*100 + (digit >= 0 ? 0.5 : -0.5))/100.0; // округление до сотых
```

Comment: А зачем ты к дробной чати добавляешь 0.5, который потом обрезается? Авось есть какой смысл - ято не шарю.

Comment: Все правильно написал отвечающий. Если кому непонятно, почему прибавляется 0.5, то замечу: истина где-то рядом.

Comment: @o2n3e: округление же!

    (int)(0.1 + 0.5) == 0
    (int)(0.8 + 0.5) == 1

Comment: Да, именно оно! Оказывается, надо было умножать и делить не на целое число( 100 ), а на дробное (100.0) =)

Answer (score 0):

Вот так

```
digit = 3.141527;
digit = (int)((digit*100))/100;
```

Comment: @KoVadim: у вас каст не с той стороны, получится деление с плавающей точкой

Comment: писал с телефона:)